# postgres and passwordless authentication

Tags: postgresql, authentication

We have users for out postgres database and none have passwords... Do not know the history behind it.

When I try to use clients to connect to these databases, for instance, pgadmin III, the connection always fails due to the lack of password.

How does one overcome this? I do not want to create username with passwords just to get around this. Sometimes that is not an option.

Thoughts?

Comment: What is the mode currently being used in `pg_hba.conf`, is it `trust` or `ident`, or something else?

Comment: you are correct that this is the settings  I need to change also the md5 one

Comment: [similar question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/8111/1396)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have administrative access to the database?

If so you can edit `pg_hba.conf` to adjust access control configuration. See http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

After you make changes issue `pg_ctl reload` or restart the database.