# PgAdmin III - How to connect to database when password is empty?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have installed PostgreSQL 9.1 on my PC (Win 7). I have a small Java application connecting successfully to it with `login=sa` and `password=""`. The connection works.

However, it is refused from PgAdmin III itself. I get:

```
Error connecting to the server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

How do I connect to my database from PgAdmin III with an empty password?

**EDIT**

This is just a test, not production code.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it's easy to imagine that PgAdmin doesn't support that.

Comment: is your Java app on the same client as pgAdmin?

Comment: [similar question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/8109/1396)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can connect to my postgres instance from pgAdmin III without a password for any user including superusers such as `postgres`.

Because you are connecting ok from another client, there is no reason you should not be able to connect from pgAdmin if they are on the same workstation - unless some firewall rule on the client itself is allowing one program but not another.

If the problem is specific to this client, you may need to change one or more of:

- pg_hba.conf

```
host    sa    all         192.168.0.nnn/32     trust
```

- postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

- the firewall on your postgres server, eg iptables:

```
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.nnn -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

**But** I recommend you don't do any of this. [The manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/auth-methods.html#AUTH-TRUST) says the following with good reason:

> trust authentication is only suitable for TCP/IP connections if you trust every user on every machine that is allowed to connect to the server by the pg_hba.conf lines that specify trust. It is seldom reasonable to use trust for any TCP/IP connections other than those from localhost (127.0.0.1).

Instead, consider either:

- using a password and md5 identification
- tunnelling port 5432 over ssh

Answer (score 33):

I found this answer elsewhere.

If your DB is on the local host, try leaving the host field blank in the connection as opposed to using “localhost” or “127.0.0.1″. This tells PgAdmin to connect via the local unix socket instead of TCP.

Comment: Let's add that the original question was about a Windows system.

Comment: Ah this was exactly it. Leaving host blank worked.

Comment: You cannot leave this field blank, it is required.

Comment: It looks like leaving the host field blank works only if you have a role in pg named as your system username (on Linux). Otherwise I guess user maps are needed.

Comment: Perfect! With a fresh install of postgresql and pgadmin, changing `pg_hba.conf` to say `trust` instead of `peer` in this line - `local all postgres trust`, and leaving the host and password fields blank in pgadmin gets everything working! I wish pgadmin would add a checkbox to switch to sockets instead of this hard to discover UI.