# Why can't pgAdmin3 connect to Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-3

I added a new user to posgresql (`amanda`) which is the same as my linux system user. At the console, I can open `psql` just fine -- I don't need a password because I'm already authenticated as `amanda`. But when I try to set up pgAdmin III without a password, I get an error:

```
An error has occurred:

01:18:47 PM: Error: Error connecting to the server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

And if I provide my system password, I get a password error:

```
An error has occurred:

01:15:30 PM: Error: Error connecting to the server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "amanda"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "amanda"
```

How do I get pgAdmin3 talking to postgres as `amanda`?

This is all @ localhost. I read this:

[PgAdmin III - How to connect to database when password is empty?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8111/pgadmin-iii-how-to-connect-to-database-when-password-is-empty)

but the answer there discusses trust authentication. My read of the [auth methods](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-TRUST) section of the manual suggests that what I want is for pgAdmin3 to use Ident Auth.

Comment: [Does this help?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8111/pgadmin-iii-how-to-connect-to-database-when-password-is-empty)

Comment: Sort of? They point to a [piece of the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-TRUST) that was a good start. I think what I'm trying to do is "ident authentication" -- not "trust authentication" though. I got it sorted by defining a password for "amanda" in psql. But I'm updating the actual question to reflect what I learned there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Unix, when psql is used without the `-h` option or a `PGHOST` variable set, it uses Unix local domain sockets, which corresponds to `local` in the `TYPE` column in `pg_hba.conf` and no `ADDR` column at all.

That differs from putting `localhost` in the host field of pgAdmin's connection dialog. This one corresponds to `host` in the `TYPE` column and `127.0.0.1` in the `ADDR` column or whatever `localhost` is resolved to by the TCP stack (with IPv6 it could be `::1` for instance).

In general, this is what is confusing when psql and pgAdmin connection attempts do not trigger the same rules in `pg_hba.conf`. If that's the case in this question, try to leave the host field in pgAdmin empty.

On top of that, Windows does not have Unix local domain sockets so `psql` on Windows defaults on `localhost` as if `-h localhost` was used.